# Sum all values from JSON response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a JSON response that looks like this:

```
{  
   "km"   =>"32.381",
   "tarifa"   =>25.6
},
{  
   "km"   =>"23423",
   "tarifa"   =>235.6
},
...
```

I want to get the sum of all tarifas. I know that I need to use `map` for this but am still confused on how to do it.

Comment: `array.map { |obj| obj.tarifa }.sum`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`Array#sum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sum):

```
array.sum { |e| e['tarifa'] }
#=> 261.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reduce to operate through the elements of a list:

`arr.map { |elt| elt["tarifa"] }.reduce(:+)` (readable way)

`arr.reduce(0) { |acc, elt| acc + elt["tarifa"] }` (former reduce way, without array regeneration)